# applying math and variables to dictionaries

Tags: python

```
import random


def d(n):
    g = random.randint(1, n)
    return g


stat_list = {'vigor': (10 + 'fortitude'),
         'fortitude': [d(6), d(6), d(6), d(6)],
         'finesse': [d(6), d(6), d(6), d(6)],
         'insight': [d(6), d(6), d(6), d(6)],
         'guile': [d(6), d(6), d(6), d(6)]}
```

I 'm trying to make an ability score system for a text adventure I am making that mimics how I would roll the scores for D&D in real life. I am rusty on top of the small amount I have taught myself about python, so I don't have much of a clue to what I am doing.

This is supposed to represent four individual rolls of a six sided die. Ones are to be rerolled, the lowest roll is to be discarded, and the remaining three are to be added together again. Should this be calculated and added into a player object, or should the operations occur initially in the player object?

These stats need to be able to change when leveling occurs and be recycled into different operations later on, so is this at all the right structure for stats to be stored in? I don't know how to proceed past what I already have here, so any tips, hints or finished products would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered maybe instead making functions to calculate each of these stats and then update the dictionary with the result?

Answer (score 1):

You have asked many questions.  You should break the task into individual steps, which is how an experienced programmer approaches every problem.  Here is an answer to one of your questions, a function to roll a 5-side die (faces numbered 2-6) four times, and return the sum of the three best rolls:

```
def roll5():
    x = [random.randint(2, 6) for _ in range(4)]
    return sum(x) - min(x)
```

BTW whe code you present will not run.  The expression `10 + 'fortitude'`attempts to add a string to an integer, which can't be done.